# Integration of NC datasests in xarray python

Tags: python, time-series, integration, netcdf, python-xarray

I am trying to spatially integrate a dataarray in xarray as to produce a time series out of it. The problem I'm facing is that after integration every value turns into 0. I guess during integration I have to exclude those 0 values. Also same thing happens with nan values ( getting all values as nan in output ). The code and result are given below.

```
t_out=ds_sst.SOSSTSST[:,60:120,295:296]
temp=t_out.integrate(['LAT','LONN179_181'])
temp
```

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Please make your problem reproducible. It’s hard to tell what is causing the problem with only a code chunk. Is this approach actually spatially integrating? That probably requires you to take cell area into account which you don’t seem to be doing

Comment: Always read help of the function (`help(t_out.integrate)`) if something does not work. There it is explicitly written: `This feature is limited to simple cartesian geometry, i.e. coord must be one dimensional.`